# Regex to get innermost text BETWEEN two characters

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am looking for a regex to get the text between innermost parenthesis .

```
    {"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"823602904340066","id":"823602904340066","time":1429276535,
"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}
```

ie

```
    `{"uid":"823602904340066","id":"823602904340066","time":1429276535,
"changed_fields":["feed"]}`
```

should show up ?Any ideas  ?

Comment: Regex as a tool for parsing JSON is hopelessly inadequate.

Comment: Please, use a JSON parser instead. Your future self will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below negated character class based regex.

```
@"\{[^}{]*\}"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zQ0eJ9/2)

`[^}{]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `{` or `}`, zero or more times.

Comment: this will not give me innermost characters.. Result : {"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"823602904340066","id":"823602904340066","time":1429276535,"changed_fields":["feed"]}

Comment: check the demo. or you mean this `@"(?<=\{)[^}{]*(?=\})"`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if we are already inside the first `{}` group, and then use balancing group construct in C# to make sure we grab the first-level nested `{}`:

```
(?<=\{[^\}]*)\{
    (?>
        ([^{}]+) 
        |    \{ (?<number>)
        |    \} (?<-number>)
    )*
    (?(number)(?!))
\}
```

Use it with `Ignore White` option.

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

I might be overcomplicating though, you might have no 2nd-level nested `{}`s.